# The formula you typed contains an error on Microsoft Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office, formula

So I'm currently writing this formula in Microsoft Excel to automate filling in one cell

=IF(M4<=3,0; "5460";"0", IF(V4="Critical"; "5460";"0", IF(I4+K4>=25500;"-5460";"0")))

Basically, what it does is checking whether cell M4 contains less than or equal to 3,0 value. If so, write "5460" in the cell. And also it checks whether cell I4 plus K4 more than or equals to 25500 then if so write minus 5460 (-5460).

But an error saying "The formula you typed contains an error" occurs. I'm not quite sure which part is wrong. I'm newbie in if-nested excel formula. Anyone knows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This if statements should replace the fail values, and the separation should be consistent. Try this:

```
=IF(M4<=3, "5460",IF(V4="Critical","5460", IF(I4+K4>=25500,"-5460","0")))
```

Or if your system is set up for semicolon separation:

```
=IF(M4<=3;"5460";IF(V4="Critical";"5460"; IF(I4+K4>=25500;"-5460";"0")))
```

Comment: The separator does not necesseraly need to be a comma. That depends on the list separator in your Windows regional settings.

Comment: Ah ok. I think it needs to be consistent though? The question has a mixture of commas and semicolons. I'll update to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use only three parameters in your if, In your example, you are using four. The "0" is redundant and makes the formula invalid.

- The value to evaluate
- The value when the evaluation is true
- The value when the evaluation is false

=IF(M4<=3,0; 5460; IF(V4="Critical"; 5460; IF(I4+K4>=25500; -5460; 0)))

Also, there is no need to put the numbers between quotes.

Comment: Are you sure the decimal separator is a comma? Is the 3,0 correct? Also, is Excel using English formulas? When I enter this in my Excel, it requires "ALS", being the Dutch variant of "IF".

Comment: Tried comma and semicolon both won't work. Yes, it is in English formulas. Should I use the =(IF(OR) formula instead?